# Hook for the "Welcome (awaiting approval)" email

Tags: 7, emails, users

I need to modify the email for "Welcome (Awaiting Approval)."

I know I can use [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7), but I don't know what the ID is for "Welcome (Awaiting Approval)," nor do I know how I can directly access a user's profile2 fields.

I assume I have to do something like:

```
function module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'welcome_waiting_approval') {
    global $user;
    $fid = $user['firm']['firm_id'];
    $message['body'][] = "Your Firm's ID is: $fid";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used the [Maillog / Mail Developer](http://drupal.org/project/maillog) module to debug things such as your question.

To find the message ID, simply use code similar to the following one:

```
function YOURMODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  dpm($message['id']); // Assuming Devel module is installed.
  // Or just ...
  print $message['id']; exit;
}
```

Hooks are run for every module they are declared in; if you don't know the message id, simply create the hook and output the message id it finds. (Exiting might actually be a bad idea if your sending many types of messages—you didn't state that—because then the code might stop short of the exact message ID you're searching for.) Since the hook is declared, it will run for each outgoing message.

To access the user's 2 profile fields, they are just fields as long as you have a user object you can access them:

```
function MYMODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  global $user; // Get's a reference to the logged in user.
  if ($message['id'] == 'welcome_message_approval') {
    $message['body'][] = t("Your Firm's ID is: @firm", array('@firm' => $user->firm);
  }
}
```

To easily access fields I recommend the [Field data extraction](http://drupal.org/project/1158878) module.

I believe the Profile2 module should "eagerly" load the profile fields. If they are not in the global user object because of lazy loading, then you should be able to get at them by calling [field_attach_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7).

Comment: Okay it works well. I can get the FID, but `$message['body'][]` is not appending to the message body. `dd($message['body'])` returns this: http://d.saew.it/Ug2O . I put ## where I want the FID to go.

Comment: $message['body'] .= 'foo'; // is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify all the users' mail on admin/config/people/accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Also incredibly useful in this case is a neat module called Mail Control
http://drupal.org/project/mailcontrol

It gives you a checkbox so you don't have to send the New User Welcome emails at all, then you can handle this with Rules or your favorite method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `hook_user_presave` for alter any mail related to registration.

If you want to alter awaiting approval mail then this condition will be helpful

```
function module_name_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) { 
    if($account->is_new) {
        //add mail you want to send as awaiting approval 
        //and disable mail from account setting
    }
}
```

hope this will be helpful